# How can I know the number of messages queued in redis pub-sub?

Tags: python-2.7, redis, publish-subscribe

Amazon SQS gives a direct number of messages available and in flight, is there a way to see the number of messages available in redis pub-sub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis' PubSub is shoot-and-forget, meaning there is no number of messages available or in flight (put differently, it is always 0).

There exists the [`PUBSUB`](https://redis.io/commands/pubsub) command that tells you about the current channels and subscribers. The same for [`INFO stats`](https://redis.io/commands/info).